# simple bootstrap controls horizontal align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm missing something with bootstrap.
I want a label/input/button combination, pushed right, **all in one row** above my table.

It should stay the same size, stacked horizontally in one row until it's too small to fit.

When I use a col-*-n, the input fills the full width of the div , causing the the elements (label and button) to wrap.

What I do **not** want to do is to put the label, button and input field each in their own col, because that will make ugly uneven gaps.

I mean, it's certainly simple enough to do with display: inline block.

Am I missing this style in the docs?

Here's my simple plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/OOWp2wmxTbeGcZfrpqQp?p=preview

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <label for="usr">Filter:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='clear()'>X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option: you can use [input-groups](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/) for your form, then float it to the right (`float-sm-right`) inside of a `col-sm-12`.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form class="float-sm-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon bg-faded text-muted">Filter</span>
            <input type="text" id="usr" class="form-control" name="usr">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click='clear()'>X</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use `form-inline` rather than `form-horizontal`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4>Previous CODE:</h4>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <label for="usr">Filter:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='clear()'>X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<h3>New Code</h3>

<p>Note: According to Bootstrap, Controls only appear inline in viewports that are <strong>at least 576px wide</strong> to account for narrow viewports on mobile devices.</p>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label for="inlineFormInput">Filter:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInput">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='clear()'>X</button>
</form>
```